# $roles must be an array of strings, or RoleInterface instances, but got object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

This is with Symfony2 and Doctrine2. I have this in my user entity:

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles->toArray();
}
```

Yet however, it is returning:

```
 array(object(Role))
```

Any ideas where I can start looking? I've been debugging for a while.

Comment: This is the current solution for Symfony 4 projects:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53732370/2400373

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the logical behavior ; by default, Doctrine2 returns a `Collection` object, and by calling `toArray()` you transform it into an array. But your array still contains `Role` objects, that are basically not strings. Of course, you can define your own methods to get it as a string, I think basically you just have to call `Role::getRole()`.

Have a look at [this article](http://blog.jmoz.co.uk/symfony2-fosuserbundle-role-entities), it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this error myself after following the [Cookbook Tutorial on Loading Users From Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database), and maybe this is your case.

It turns out I forgot to implement the `RoleInterface` on my `Role` entity object (the one referenced by my `User` entity). That was it.