# Symfony login authentication returning Error: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on a website that is built using symfony 2.5, the requirement was that each user needs to have a only one role (user cannot have more than 1 role) so in users table where the username and passwords go there is another column by the name `role` which holds `ROLE_ADMIN` for admin people and `ROLE_STAFF` for company staff, so while authenticating if my `getRoles` function looks like the following i am able to login just fine as an admin

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return array('ROLE_ADMIN');
}
```

since i cannot hard code the role and it needs to be fetched from database so if i change this to get the role from the **role** column of **user** table

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->getRole();
}
// getter for $role 
public function getRole()
{
    return $this->role->toArray();
}
```

I get the error

> Error: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-objec

I will really appreciate if someone can help me fix this, please note that i do not need many to many relation ships for the role just one role per user and hance want to avoid creating another entity like cook book example.

If it helps this is my entire `User` Entity

```
<?php

namespace ClickTeck\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * User
 */

class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $role;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
        $this->role = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        //return $this->role;
        return $this->getRole();

        //return array('ROLE_ADMIN');
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
                $this->id,
                $this->username,
                $this->password,
                $this->salt,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->salt
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param string $role
     * @return User
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRole()
    {

        return $this->role->toArray();


    }
}
```

I also need to mention suppose if i dont turn the roles to array i get the error

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct() must be of the type array, string given,

Comment: `$this->role` is not initialized

Comment: Please provide us with your mapping information. If you have string value why do you think that it will work with `toArray()` method on it? In many other languages you can have this construction. But not in PHP: in PHP all primitive types are just primitives, not objects! They don't have any methods that can be called on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `toArray()` method on your non-object variable. It's PHP. There are no universal object that extended by all primitive types. Primitives are not objects.

Your variable `$role` as described in your Entity has `string` type. If you want to create array with this variable you can just call:

```
array($this->role);
```

But as described in your PHPDoc for method `public function getRole()` you want to retrieve string. And so you doesn't need array. Just return `$this->role`.

To implement `UserInterface` you need to return array of all the roles for your user. You can just return `array($this->role)` in your `getRoles()` method:

```
public function getRoles()
{
    return array($this->role);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking out time, if i return it as a string i get the error `Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct() must be of the type array, string given,`, i did manage to fix it a couple of minutes ago and will be adding my answer, you are pretty close though

Comment: you just need to `return array($this->role);` in your getRoles method

Comment: Thanks is perfect solution on Symfony 3.3.x

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution for me in Symfony 3 and Symfony 4 when I use a Role field in the same table:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26359914/2400373

But in another project using Symfony 4 create an additional table called Role so that you can work with them you must make these changes in the `getRoles()`

```
public function getRoles()
{
   //return array('ROLE_USER');
   return array($this->role->getRol());
}
```

In this way the array returns the Role of the logged in user